# Find max of rows from specific columns and extract column name and corresponding row value from another column

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is a data structure that I have:

```
structure(list(UDD_beta = c(1.17136554204268, 0.939587997289016
), UDD_pval = c(0, 0), UDD_R.sq = c(0.749044972637797, 0.516943886705951
), SSX_beta = c(1.05356804780772, 0.927948300464624), SSX_pval = c(0, 
0), SSX_R.sq = c(0.60226298037862, 0.629111666509209), SPP_beta = c(0.675765151939885, 
0.516425218613404), SPP_pval = c(0, 0), SPP_R.sq = c(0.479849538274406, 
0.378266618442121), EEE_beta = c(0.690521022226874, 0.639380962824289
), EEE_pval = c(0, 0), EEE_R.sq = c(0.585610742768951, 0.676073352909597
)), .Names = c("UDD_beta", "UDD_pval", "UDD_R.sq", "SSX_beta", 
"SSX_pval", "SSX_R.sq", "SPP_beta", "SPP_pval", "SPP_R.sq", 
"EEE_beta", "EEE_pval", "EEE_R.sq"), row.names = c("DDK", "DDL"
), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to take `R.sq` columns and for each row find the max and the column name of the max value. Then take corresponding `beta`. Expected output:

```
    Name Value
DDK UDD 1.17136554204268
DDL EEE 0.690521022226874
```

Sorry, the second expected value should be `0.639380962824289`.

Comment: Now that I read it again, it seems the wrong value is the first one (no `R.sq` in that col)

Comment: There's UDD_R.sq column. Or are you referring to other problem?

Comment: But I want to extract UDD_beta ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `max.col`.  Subset the columns of interest i.e. columns that have 'R.sq' using the `grep`, then get the column index of `max` value with `max.col`.  Use that to get the column names and also the values that correspond to a particular row (`row/column` indexing)

```
i1 <- grep("R.sq", names(df1))
i2 <- max.col(df1[i1], "first")
i3 <- grep("beta", names(df1))
res <- data.frame(Names = sub("_.*", "", names(df1)[i1][i2]), 
               Value = df1[i3][cbind(1:nrow(df1), i2)])
row.names(res) <- row.names(df1)
```

Comment: This does not agree with OP. I think mine doesn't either but I m not sure what OP wants

Comment: @Sotos I am not getting the logic.  If it is based on 'beta' column, why the two values are from the same row.  Shouldn't it be 0.63981

Comment: @akrun OP provided wrong expected output (this is my guess)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `tidyverse` approach via `gather`ing your df to long and filtering both `R.sq` vars and max value, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 rownames_to_column('ID') %>% 
 gather(var, val, -ID) %>% 
 filter(grepl('R.sq|beta', var)) %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 mutate(max1=as.integer(val == max(val[grepl('R.sq', var)]))) %>% 
 group_by(ID, grp = sub('_.*', '', var)) %>% 
 filter(!all(max1 == 0) & grepl('beta', var)) %>% 
 ungroup() %>% select(-c(max1, grp))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 3
>      ID      var      val
>   <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>
> 1   DDK UDD_beta 1.171366
> 2   DDL EEE_beta 0.639381
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
sub_data <- data[grep("R.sq", colnames(data))]
colnames(sub_data) <- gsub("_R.sq", "", colnames(sub_data))
sub_data$Name <- NA
sub_data$Value <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(sub_data)){
  sub_data$Name[i] <- names(sub_data[i,])[which.max(apply(sub_data[i,], 2, max))]
  sub_data$Value[i] <- max(data[grep(paste0(sub_data$Name[i], "_beta"), colnames(data))], na.rm=T)
}
sub_data[c("Name", "Value")]
#    Name    Value
#DDK  UDD 1.171366
#DDL  EEE 0.690521
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Need ID for all possible betas and Rsq
ID <- gsub("_R.sq", "", grep("_R.sq$", names(INPUT), value = TRUE))
dummy <- function(x) {
    # Find out which Rsq is largest
    i <- ID[which.max(x[paste0(ID, "_R.sq")])]
    # Extract beta for largest Rsq
    data.frame(Name = i, Value = x[paste0(i, "_beta")])
}
do.call("rbind", apply(INPUT, 1, dummy))
```

Comment: Even though now that I edited my answer we get the same results, they don't agree with OP output.

Comment: @Sotos How does yours or mine answer doesn't agree with OPs output?

Comment: Second value of the output is `0.6905...` - corresponding to first row `beta`.. yours (and mine) aren't

Comment: @Sotos OP provided wrong expected output (this is my guess)